# Woocommerce YITH Product Addon Alignment

Tags: woocommerce

How can I change the product addons to align to the left and not all centred.

I am using the Joyas Pro theme

http://iains14.sg-host.com/product/dg-wood-sunglass/

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd5j3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using CSS. Add the CSS on the product CSS

[image]

```css
.ywapo_input_container {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.ywapo_group_container.form-row.form-row-wide h3 {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for helping.  Things were going well until this bit happened and you have just solved it.  Thank you.